# ESP8266: Multiple analog inputs using software

Tags: esp8266

Is there a way to get at least three analog inputs to the esp8266 (without a multiplexer)?

Each digital or analog pin on an Arduino can be configured as digital or "analog" (e.g., [PWM software](https://github.com/Palatis/arduino-softpwm)).

Here is a way to squeeze one additional analog input pin: [hackaday.io/project/8435-2-analog-inputs-for-esp8266-without-multiplexer](https://hackaday.io/project/8435-2-analog-inputs-for-esp8266-without-multiplexer)

Any ideas or software[?](https://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=19521)

Comment: it depends on what you're feeding it. if it can be crude, you might be able to use mosfets.

Answer (score 2):

1) nope it's not possible "in a straightforward way". you should use analog muxes.

2) the statement "Each digital or analog pin on an Arduino can be configured as digital or "analog" (e.g., PWM software)." means for PWM or the so called "analog output". not intended the ADC unit.

3) the link provided uses software tricks to measure 2 signals in a muxed fashion. it's up to purpose.

workarounds :

1) use CD4066 CMOS bilateral switch. it works with analog signals.

2) use GPIOs to supply voltage to measurement units. like the link you provided. it works for passives like photoresistors and for devices like LM35 temp sensor. but can't be used for devices like 3 channels analog-out accelerometers.

Comment: Um, for (2), I put it in quotes for that very reason.